# parse.com scheduling a background job via REST api

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

Using Parse.com,
I am trying to run a background job from cloud code.

I managed to do it via the RESP api with a `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` call from cloud code

This actually runs the background job immediately but I need to schedule it. I am assuming there is data to set in the "payload", something like `{"start:{ "__type": "Date", "iso": "2014-02-17T23:28:28.943Z"}}` but this does not work. 
Any help appreciated.